# Change default display options for Google Gadgets with Userperfs? (for Google Sites)

Tags: html, css, xml, google-sites, google-gadget

The [Gadget documentation](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/dev_guide) is some of the worst I've seen.

[This section](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/xml_reference#Moduleprefs_Ref) details the ModulePref settings available but although their example lists **height="200"** as an option the following attribute list table doesn't mention height.

The example nor the table mention width, which I've found you can set **but only if you set a pixel amount greater than 100 otherwise it assumes percentage** (where is this in the docs Google?).

Anyway rant aside, **how can I set the other display options defaults?**

- Include a scrollbar on gadget when necessary (this comes unticked by default, thats fine)
- Include a border around gadget (this is infuriatingly ticked by default and makes Gadget look terrible)
- Display title on gadget (see above)

Looking for a better / more patient man than me to find where these are.

I've tried `border="none"` under the `<ModulePrefs>` but no joy.

Thanks